# Appium IOS - element.getAttribute("value") is returning null for XCUIElementTypeTextField although value is present

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I am working in Appium for iOS Mobile App built using React Native.

In one page, XCUIElementTypeTextField is having value. But when I retrieve it using getAttribute("value"), its returning null.

[image: XCUIElementTypeTextField Error Image]

```
WebElement firstName = MobileBy.iOSClassChain("**/XCUIElementTypeOther[`name == 'First Name'`]/**/XCUIElementTypeTextField[1]");
String actualValue = firstName.getAttribute("value");
```

I tried with other attributes like: innerText, name, getText(). But none worked for me. The same XCUIElementTypeTextField in other page is working fine. Only in this page, am getting problem.
XCode Version: 11.1 
Appium Version: 1.15.1 
Appium Java Client: 7.2.0 
Selenium version: 3.141.59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13594

As mentioned in the above github issue:

> The issue is known and is XCTest regression. Use Xcode 10 SDK to test
>   iOS 12 and below and Xcode11 for iOS13.

My ios device is 12.3.1 and my xcode was 11. So changed to xcode 10 and it is working fine now.